# WHERE vs HAVING calculated field with multiple IFs/LIKEs

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, having-clause

If i'm not wrong when using having, the query is executed without any filters then the code go over all the result to apply the filter. But in this case I'm using multiple Like//If to calculate my order. I was wondering what would be better between:

```
SELECT Page.*, 

if  (`flags` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'),

    if  (`title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'),
        5,
        3
    ),

    if  (`title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'),
        2,
        0
    ),
) as pageOrder

FROM Page

WHERE `flags` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') OR `title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')

ORDER BY pageOrder DESC
```

or

```
SELECT Page.*, 

if  (`flags` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'),

    if  (`title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'),
        5,
        3
    ),

    if  (`title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%'),
        2,
        0
    ),
) as pageOrder

FROM Page

HAVING pageOrder > 0

ORDER BY pageOrder DESC
```

using mysql 5.7 and php 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *this* case, there is not much difference.  Here's an analysis.

- Since no index can be used for either the `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`, the entire table will be scanned (for either formulation).
- Expressions are usually a small part of the entire query, so *usually* I would ignore the `LIKEs`.  But, in this case, you are doing 3-4 `LIKEs` for every row, about twice as many `LIKEs` for the `WHERE` approach, so it might be somewhat slower.
- One *could* argue that the `WHERE` is more readable.
- All the columns, most of the rows, of `Page` will be shoveled into a tmp table.  But I don't see a big difference between the two approaches.  Also, I don't necessarily see a way to avoid the issue.

Here is a slightly more compact, but not faster, way to formulate the pageOrder expression:

```
  3 * (`flags` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') +
  2 * (`title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
```